# Google api, where to put all those jars

Tags: java, eclipse, google-api

I downloaded google Api (flights: qpxExpress), I end up with a zip file full of jars:

```
zip file
|____________dependencies
|____________libs
|____________lib-sources
|____________.classpath
|____________google_api.jar
```

I associated the google_api.jar with the build path of my project, but where to put the rest of jars (libs, lib sources...), please help?

Comment: Regarding iOS or what ?

Comment: I'm working with Eclipse, it's in the build path => add jar but here I can only add the google _api.jar, so what about the rest where to put them?

Comment: Java  Google api Integration ?

Comment: yes, how to integrate the API

Comment: okay , just try what he answered. i hope it will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put it in lib and make build path settings in case of normal standalone app or  inside WEB-INF/lib folder for webapp

Comment: Thank's for the reply, but put what in the lib, the google_api jar or libs, dependencies folder that contains jars also or all the file?

Comment: All the .jar files of lib folder

Comment: Thank you for the answer, i added the libs with the build path and attach each jar with the jar source, it looks fine for now my journey starts with this API, any help [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29915359/google-api-how-to-get-the-results-in-java)?